# How to flatten multi index (that really has one level) in Pandas? value_counts only returns multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Pandas 1.1.4

Consider

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

counts = df4.value_counts().astype(np.int)

print(counts.index)

counts.reindex(counts.index.to_flat_index())

print(counts.index)

print(counts.index.to_flat_index())
```

output:

> ```
> MultiIndex([(4,),
>             (3,),
>             (2,),
>             (1,)],
>            names=['a'])
> MultiIndex([(4,),
>             (3,),
>             (2,),
>             (1,)],
>            names=['a'])
> Index([(4,), (3,), (2,), (1,)], dtype='object')
> ```

I want to be able to interchange with

```
df5 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
print(df5.index)
```

whose `index` is

Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64').

Please notice `df4`'s index is the same as `df5`'s, but the `value_counts` makes it into a multi index.

---

How to I work around this? No flatten I try seems to work.

Comment: `df.value_counts` was introduced shortly after v 1.0 I believe

Comment: Why not `df['a'].value_counts()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `QuangHoang` Always there to the rescue :) It does solve the problem, but I would still like to know how to handle the index problem directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the index from the 0th level of the multiindex like so:

```
>>> counts.index.get_level_values(0)
Int64Index([4, 3, 2, 1], dtype='int64', name='a')
```

Then you can swap the index out for these values like so:

```
new_index = pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
new_counts = counts.set_axis(
    counts.index.get_level_values(0).map(new_index)
)

print(new_counts)
a
8    1
7    1
6    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

But you can simply call `.value_counts()` on the column itself to avoid having play around with the multiindex at all:

```
df['a'].value_counts()
```

Comment: why the `.map(new_index)`?

Comment: Didn't you want to interchange the index with the index from `df5`? as per your question?

Comment: I thought `counts.set_axis(counts.index.get_level_values(0), inplace=True)` does that. I don't understand the map

Comment: That does do it- however it will align everything based on their position. Using `.map` ensures that on your index you swap the values `5 -> 1; 6 -> 2; 7 ->3; 8 -> 4` regardless of their order in the originating index. I guess I'm not sure what you want to do with the latter part of your question `df5 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])`

Comment: Yes I understand now. I do need the map (I used a different method, but you did understand)

Answer (score 0):

When pandas creates a dataframe from a dictionary like in this case, it assumes the keys of the passed dict should be the columns of the resulting DataFrame.  If the keys should be rows you should initialise your dataframe as follows:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, orient='index')
```

when you then run :

```
print(counts.index.to_flat_index())
```

you get

```
Index([(1, 2, 3, 4)], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Actually, they should be columns. I expect `a` to be a column. But good to know, that was new to me.